# Confluent HDFS Sink Connector : Kafka Topic with plain string format to HDFS in Parquet format fails with Avro schema must be a record error

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have installed docker confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:4.0.0 image in my virtual machine. I am interested in getting the kafka topic which is a plain text data (string format) in hdfs in parquet format.

```
sudo docker run -d \
    --name=kafka-connect \
    --net=host \
    -e CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=<kafka-server-host>:9092 \
    -e CONNECT_REST_PORT=8082 \
    -e CONNECT_GROUP_ID="connect-kafkac1" \
    -e CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC="connect-kafkac1-config" \
    -e CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC="connect-kafkac1-offsets" \
    -e CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC="connect-kafkac1-status" \
    -e CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER="org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter" \
    -e CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER="org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter" \
    -e CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER="org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter" \
    -e CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER="org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter" \
    -e CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME="localhost" \
    -e CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS=org.reflections=ERROR \
    -e CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/share/java \
    confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:4.0.0
```

I have the below configurations done.

***/etc/kafka/connect-standalone.properties***

```
bootstrap.servers=kafkaclusteraddress:9092
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false
```

***/etc/kafka-connect-hdfs/quickstart-hdfs.properties***

```
name=hdfs-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=<topicname>
topics.dir=<hdfs-topic-dir>
logs.dir=<hdfs-logs-dir>
hdfs.url=<hdfs-url>:8020
format.class=io.confluent.connect.hdfs.parquet.ParquetFormat
flush.size=3
hadoop.conf.dir=/etc/hadoop/conf
hadoop.home=/usr/bin/hadoop
```

***error i receive after running the config in standalone mode***

```
# connect-standalone /etc/kafka/connect-standalone.properties /etc/kafka-connect-hdfs/quickstart-hdfs.properties

----------------------------------------

[2018-02-13 19:11:09,542] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=hdfs-sink-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted. (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Avro schema must be a record.
        at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroSchemaConverter.convert(AvroSchemaConverter.java:113)
        at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroParquetWriter.writeSupport(AvroParquetWriter.java:144)
        at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroParquetWriter.<init>(AvroParquetWriter.java:106)
        at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.parquet.ParquetRecordWriterProvider$1.write(ParquetRecordWriterProvider.java:68)
        at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.TopicPartitionWriter.writeRecord(TopicPartitionWriter.java:635)
        at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.TopicPartitionWriter.write(TopicPartitionWriter.java:379)
        at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.DataWriter.write(DataWriter.java:374)
        at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkTask.put(HdfsSinkTask.java:101)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:495)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:288)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:198)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:166)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:170)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:214)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2018-02-13 19:11:09,545] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=hdfs-sink-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:517)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:288)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:198)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:166)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:170)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:214)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Avro schema must be a record.
        at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroSchemaConverter.convert(AvroSchemaConverter.java:113)
        at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroParquetWriter.writeSupport(AvroParquetWriter.java:144)
        at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroParquetWriter.<init>(AvroParquetWriter.java:106)
        at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.parquet.ParquetRecordWriterProvider$1.write(ParquetRecordWriterProvider.java:68)
        at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.TopicPartitionWriter.writeRecord(TopicPartitionWriter.java:635)
        at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.TopicPartitionWriter.write(TopicPartitionWriter.java:379)
        at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.DataWriter.write(DataWriter.java:374)
        at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkTask.put(HdfsSinkTask.java:101)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:495)
        ... 10 more
[2018-02-13 19:11:09,545] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=hdfs-sink-0} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the stacktrace, it is expecting Avro data, not Strings.

```
IllegalArgumentException: Avro schema must be a record.
        at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroSchemaConverter.convert(AvroSchemaConverter.java:113)
        at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroParquetWriter.writeSupport(AvroParquetWriter.java:144)
        at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroParquetWriter.<init>(AvroParquetWriter.java:106)
```

I've not personally tested JSON to Parquet, but as a columnar datatype, `ParquetFormat` requires that you have a schema. Since you have `schemas.enable=false`, that won't happen, and so it cannot consume plain string, ints, booleans, etc and other "non-structured" Connect API types.

These are the settings that need altered.

```
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
```

In order to set the JSONConverter to have `schemas.enable=true`, then you must produce data that looks like `{"schema": {...}, "payload": {...}}`, where, the `schema` field contains the type definitions of the object within the `payload` field

Otherwise, if you have control over the producer code, you should send Avro data instead, which will require using the Schema Registry.

---

I would like to mention that since you have just a string record, then Parquet won't have much benefits over a raw text file on HDFS since there will only be a single column anyway.